# SQL UNION ALL only include newer entries from 'bottom' table

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Fair warning: I'm new to using SQL. I do so on an Oracle server either via AQT or with SQL Developer.

As I haven't been able to think or search my way to an answer, I put myself in your able hands...

I'd like to combine data from table A (high quality data) with data from table B (fresh data) such that the entries from B are only included when the date stamp are later than those available from table A.

Both tables include entries from multiple entities, and the latest date stamp varies with those entities.

On the 4th of january, the tables may look something like:

```
A____________________________          B_____________________________
entity  date     type   value           entity  date     type   value
X       1.jan    1      1               X       1.jan    1      2
X       1.jan    0      1               X       1.jan    0      2
X       2.jan    1      1               X       2.jan    1      2
Y       1.jan    1      1    (new entry)X       3.jan    1      1
Y       3.jan    1      1               Y       1.jan    1      2
                                        Y       3.jan    1      2
                             (new entry)Y       4.jan    1      1
```

I have made an attempt at some code that I hope clarify my need:

```
WITH
AA AS 
(SELECT entity, date, SUM(value)
FROM table_A
GROUP BY
entity,
date),

BB AS
(SELECT entity, date, SUM(value)
FROM table_B
WHERE date > ALL (SELECT date FROM AA)
GROUP BY
entity,
date
)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM AA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM BB)
```

Now, if the `WHERE date > ALL (SELECT date FROM AA)`would work seperately for each entity, I think have what I need.

That is, for each entity I want all entries from A, and only newer entries from B.

As the data in table A often differ from that of B (values are often corrected) I dont think I can use something like: `table A UNION ALL (table B MINUS table A)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question confusing, because I don't know where the aggregation is coming from.

The basic idea on getting newer rows from `table_b` uses conditions in the `where` clause, something like this:

```
select . . .
from table_a a
union all
select . . .
from table_b b
where b.date > (select max(a.date) from a where a.entity = b.entity);
```

You can, of course, run this on your CTEs, if those are what you really want to combine.

Comment: The aggregation is over all values for one entity on a single date. Using table A, X has SUM(value) = 2 on 1. jan. More to the point: Doesn't the 'select max(a.date) from...' return a single max_date? I would like one for each entity...

Comment: @Kjetil . . . As I say in the answer, just run this using the CTEs you have defined.

Comment: I feel a bit sheepish as I didn't know that max() could return multiple values. Thanks so much for putting up with a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are looking for entries in BB which do not exist in AA. When you are doing `date > ALL (SELECT date FROM AA)` this will not take into consideration the entity in question and you will not get the correct records. 
Alternative is to use the `JOIN` and filter out all matching entries with AA.

Something like below.

```
WITH
AA AS 
(SELECT entity, date, SUM(value)
FROM table_A
GROUP BY
entity,
date),

BB AS
(SELECT entity, date, SUM(value)
FROM table_B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN AA
   ON AA.entity = BB.entity
   AND AA.DATE = BB.date
WHERE AA.date == null
GROUP BY
entity,
date
)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM AA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM BB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` , it will remove the duplicate records

```
   SELECT * FROM (
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM AA 
                    UNION  
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM BB   )
```

Comment: The problem with this, I think, is that the old entries in A are not identical with the old ones in B (data in A is reviewed for errors and whatnot). How will UNION know to ignore changes..?

Comment: @Kjetil If the old entries in B are not same as A, then we should consider it as a new entry.. right?